# SQL Time function

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, time

Hi i am writing a SQL query for a report which will give the amounts of leads coming in for the day since 8am. The report is set to go out every our so for example the 8am report will show leads which came in from 7am-8am and the 9am report will show from 7am-9am the 10am from 7am-10am and so on, i would like to know if someone could provide me with the time function to put in the `where` cluase (something along the lines of:

`T.LeadDate >=  DATEADD(d, DATEDIFF(d, 0, GETDATE()), 0) -1)`

thanks

Comment: Please show what you have tried and schema of your table? Most importantly column details will help alot.

Comment: Based upon your other questions and the syntax of your example, I assume this is for SQL Server?

Comment: Does the day start at 7am or 8am?

Comment: Not exactly sure what you are trying to do but I gave it a shot in my answer

Comment: @TimLehner yes it's for SQL Server and it starts at 8am

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will get you everything with a LeadDate after 7a.m. of the current day

```
select * from TABLENAME t where t.LeadDate >= dateadd(hh,7, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, GETDATE()))
```

You could also use the following, which seems a little clearer to me.

```
select * from TABLENAME t where t.LeadDate >= dateadd(hh,7, CONVERT(datetime,CONVERT(date, getdate())))
```

Comment: thank you very much Kevin this seems to have done the trick i greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

```
WHERE T.LeadDate >= DATEADD(hh,7,DATEDIFF(D, 0, GETDATE()))
```

There is no need to cast the `DATEDIFF(D, 0, GETDATE())` part back to a time

Answer (score 0):

For completeness' sake, this will get you the count per day considering your rule:

```
-- Get counts of records per day
-- Anything prior to 8am is considered the prior day.
select cast(dateadd(hh, -8, MyDate) as date) FiscalDate, count(*) as Num
from MyTable
group by cast(dateadd(hh, -8, MyDate) as date)
order by cast(dateadd(hh, -8, MyDate) as date)
```